# Eclipse with Android does not respond

Tags: android, eclipse, response, apk, installation

I've installed Eclipse and the Android SDK but I just cant get to everything working properly. After 2 days I managed to create a working emulator that actually shows am Android interface (instead of a black screen with Android text), but I have absolutely no idea why it didnt work for the first two days. After that, I´ve had problems with the ADB and I also managed to fix that. And still my problems aren't over. I now have a problem with installing the sample APK files into my emulator, but I dont get any error messages, which makes it really hard to find a solution for.

I.e. I've loaded 2 different projects (bbbb and Snake) and after pressing run the emulator starts up. BUt then, nothing happens. I have copy-pasted an exert of the console below.

```
[2011-10-21 20:29:59 - bbbb] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-10-21 20:29:59 - bbbb] Device API version is 14 (Android 4.0.1)
[2011-10-21 20:29:59 - bbbb] Uploading bbbb.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-21 20:29:59 - bbbb] Installing bbbb.apk...
[2011-10-21 20:59:28 - Snake] ------------------------------
[2011-10-21 20:59:28 - Snake] Android Launch!
[2011-10-21 20:59:28 - Snake] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-21 20:59:28 - Snake] Performing com.example.android.snake.Snake activity launch
[2011-10-21 20:59:31 - Snake] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-10-21 20:59:31 - Snake] Device API version is 14 (Android 4.0.1)
[2011-10-21 20:59:31 - Snake] Uploading Snake.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-21 20:59:31 - Snake] Installing Snake.apk...
```

As you can see, the console just stops after the Installing .apk... line (and yes I have waited for 30 minutes just to be sure). Why don't I get a time-out or error message?
I really dont know what to do now. And I cant find any answers on this on the web. Can anyone please help me. I really want to start some actual programming instead of this. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Your app does not specify a API level. Go to Window ----> Preferences and  then android. Pick a API level.

Comment: I fixed the WARNING, but the error still remains meaning that absolutely nothing happens after the message "Installing .apk...". I don't receive any errors or time-outs. I also cannot find the app anywhere in the emulator device. Is this normal and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with Snake.apk, you should try starting with the example project that is created when you create a new android project with eclipse.
Alternatively you can create a new project with the android command like this:

```
android create project --target 9 --name HelloWorld --path . --activity HelloWorld --package com.example.helloworld
```

After you've created this, make an emulator with version 2.3 (android 9) and try that.
I don't know if you should mess with android 14 yet if you aren't familiar with android at all given no device out yet has Ice cream sandwich yet so you won't be able to test with a real device until next month at least.
If you are planning to target honeycomb (tablet) devices you can start with version 13 and create an emulator for that. By the way, what are the specs like on your PC? It takes a pretty fast machine to run the emulator. The android emulator is notoriously slow.

Anyways, I'd start with the most basic of projects, which is the template project android creates for you when you start a new project.. Once that works you can continue with your own project.

Answer (score 0):

create new AVD with 1.5 sdk version.
Try to start with minimum  sdk version(1.5).and specify your minimum sdk version while creating project.
also make the emulator skin as ***qvga***(smallest).